# New App missing from django admin panel

Tags: django

I'm working on one of django tutorials, creating a blog and I ran into an issue with seeing the new app in django admin panel. 
http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/index.html

I looked at it back and forth and I cant seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Below is what I have so far.

```
    from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)
def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'
```

---

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

---

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]
```

Then this is what I have in the terminal.

```
Migrations for 'blog':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Post
(project1) michaels-mbp-2:project1 michaelp$ python manage.py migrate blog
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: blog
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying blog.0001_initial... OK
```

Comment: I take it that the `Post` class has not been transcribed into the question properly? There is a problem with the indentation of that code.

Comment: do you use a custom admin root site? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite. If so, then when you register your models, you need to register them to your custom site instance, not `admin.site`.

Comment: What file is `admin.site.register(Post)` in? You shouldn't need to create `BlogConfig` - that doesn't appear to be part of the tutorial.